# new JFrame() crashes when calling main() entry point from JNI

Tags: java, java-native-interface

I've got the following Java program (OpenJDK6, FreeBSD 9.1):

```
package test;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public final class Application 
{
  private void go1()
  {
    JFrame x = new JFrame();
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) 
  {
    new Application().go1();
  }
}
```

I've written a trivial C++ program that initializes JVM and invokes `Application.main()`:

```
#include <jni.h>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
  JavaVM *jvm;
  JNIEnv *env;
  JavaVMInitArgs vm_args;
  JavaVMOption* options = new JavaVMOption[1];
  options[0].optionString = "-Djava.class.path=my/path1:my/path2";
  vm_args.version = JNI_VERSION_1_6;
  vm_args.nOptions = 1;
  vm_args.options = options;
  vm_args.ignoreUnrecognized = false;
  JNI_CreateJavaVM(&jvm, (void **)&env, &vm_args);
  jclass cls = env->FindClass("test/Application");
  jmethodID method = env->GetStaticMethodID(cls, "main", "([Ljava/lang/String;)V");
  jobject arr = env->NewObjectArray(0, str, 0);
  env->CallStaticVoidMethod(cls, method, arr);
  char ch;
  std::cin >> ch;
}
```

Where I run the above C++ program, it finds the `Application` class and calls `main` method successfully, but then I encounter segfault at `JFrame x = new JFrame()` line (for the sake of readability, I've omitted trace lines, like `std::cout << "I'm here"` and `System.out.println("Here we are")`).

If I add `env->FindClass("javax/swing/JFrame")` etc to the JNI code, it's able to find the class and to create it without a problem. Besides, if I create in Java some "built-in" class, like `String`, it succeeds.

So, what could be the reason that Java code fails to create `JFrame` within the main thread that started from JNI?

Comment: What happens if you change the code so that the JFrame is created on the EDT.

Comment: @Hovercraft Full Of Eels : then `SwingUtilities.invokeAndWait` segfaults (even with empty `Runnable`)`.

Comment: I would use `SwingUtilities.invokeLater(...)`, but fear you may run into the same problem.

Comment: @Hovercraft Full Of Eels , alas, same problem. I suspect I miss something in the VM initialization process, but the above snippet appears in JNI tutorials...

Comment: Sounds like a memory management problem. Maybe you're not supposed to delete `options` as long as the VM is running (and if you do, do it correctly: `delete [] options`).

Comment: @Codo oh, what a shame :( It was a blind copy&paste from some "example"... Anyway, removing this line doesn't affect the problem.

Comment: @Codo besides, please note that I'm *able* to create objects - just not Swing ones. So it's most likely related to Swing initialization...

Answer (score 1):

I believe you can get an exception from Java on "new JFrame()" if you are running headless.  If you are running in Linux, there is a chance that C is not giving Java an environment with a windowing system.  I'd expect the same results if you were running in a Windows environment with no GUI attached (Perhaps a system process running as a service).

However I'm currently seeing this problem in an otherwise happy windows system, so I can't say this is the only possible cause.